# Viable way to ruin a milk corporation?

Tags: network, virus, physical, programming, crime

Hack into their system and change the "Sell by" date so that it is immediately bad. How long do you think until they notice, if you pull it off?

Comment: Not sure if I should laugh at this or cry.

Comment: That seems like a lot of work. Have you considered cowpox?

Answer (score 9):

I would expect it would be noticed almost immediately by quality control at the factory, or by their first customers when they enter their product into their inventory management system.

If you really wanted to ruin a milk corporation, it would be more effective to compromise their Public Relations offices' Twitter and email accounts, and issue fake press releases apologizing for the fecal contamination in their products...

Comment: Even then I'd suggest that would be a better way to embarrass a dairy company than to "ruin" them.

Comment: I don't think people would take the press release seriously. It might be better to issue a denial about the fact that there's fecal contamination that exceeds the legal guidelines and that corp X things that the legal guidelines for fecal contamination are quite alright.